# Associvity and Distributive property of Matrix Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, associativity

Matrix multiplication is associative $(AB)C=A(BC)$

What about the case when $AB$ results in a scalar?
Considering the case when $A$ is $1 \times n$  dimensional, $B$ and $C$ are both $n \times 1$ dimensional, the product $AB$ would result in a scalar which can be multiplied by $C$, i.e., $(AB)C=kC$.

However, $BC$ can not multiplied. Hence $A(BC)$ is not possible... I must be missing something here!

I came across this when checking gradient of least squares function... which resulted in $(y - W'\phi(x))\cdot\phi(x)$  where $y$ is scalar, $\phi(x)$ and $W$ are both $n$ dimensional column vector.
By distributive property, multiplying resulted in the multiplication $W'\cdot\phi(x)\cdot\phi(x)$

$W' = \operatorname{tranpose}(W)$

Comment: B and C can't be both n x 1 dimensional, that not a legal combination. The question is not properly formed.   When one of the matrix products results in a 1x1 matrix, this is not a scalar.  Normal rules of matrix multiplication still apply when multiplying 1x1 matrices by 1xN or Nx1 matrices.

Comment: Consider B And C and W to be nx1 dimensional, y a scalar. Now the gradient of (y-w'*b)^2 wrt w is equal to -2(y- w'*b)*b..now when i open out the bracket i get the problematic w'*b * b..so im not allow to open it up?

Comment: (y-w'*b)^2 - this doesn't make sense, you can't subtract a 1x1 matrix from a scalar, you'd have to convert one so they are of the same type.  Where did this formula come from?  I guess some software packages may be more tolerant of this type of thing, but from matrix algebra point of view its not legal

Comment: it is the cost function of linear regression! (y - w'x)^2 where w are the weights and the x are the feature..maybe y can be thought of as 1 x 1..still i dont understand how the gradient takes that form

Comment: I see, you are taking the difference of the sum of squares (weighted).  I guess w'x is actually the scalar (dot) product of two vectors which you can apply the gradient operator to - you need to look up in vector analysis book for the formula and simplifications you can make when taking the gradient of expressions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that, formally speaking, we cannot multiply a $1\times1$ matrix with a matrix of any size. However, we have the following identifications, which respect the linear structure:

$$ \{ \text{Scalars} \} \leftrightarrow \{ 1 \times 1 \text{ matrices} \} \leftrightarrow  \{ \text{Scalar matrices of any size} \}.$$

Thus, under this identification, it makes sense to multiply *any* matrix $C$ by a scalar $\lambda$: if $C$ has size $m \times n$, you can view $\lambda$ as the $m \times m$ scalar matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & & &\\ & \lambda & &\\ & & \ddots & \\ & & & \lambda\end{pmatrix} = \lambda I_m$$
and the product $\lambda C$ corresponds to $(\lambda I_m) C$, which is a well-defined matrix product.

---

In your particular problem, you are considering $(y-W'\phi)\cdot \phi$, where $\phi$ is $n \times 1$. According to what I said above, if you want to interpret the scalar multiplication "$\cdot$" as matrix multiplication, you need to view $y$ and $W'\phi$ as $n \times n$ scalar matrices. But really in either case all that you are doing is multiplying all the entries of $\phi$ by the scalar $(y - W'\phi)$. I think you are confused because you think the operation between $W'$ and $\phi$ is the same as the operation $\cdot$ between $W'\phi$ and $\phi$. But the first one is matrix multiplication, whereas the second one is scalar-matrix multiplication.

Comment: But the doubt i had is that BC can not be multipliedd..since they are of same dimension..however i understand from your explanation (AB)C is defined..but shouldnt A(BC) be defined as well

Comment: @SridharThiagarajan The point I am trying to make is that while neither $(AB)C$ nor $A(BC)$ are defined in the situation you presented, it is possible to think of scalar-matrix multiplication as a special case of matrix multiplication.

Comment: @SridharThiagarajan You say "$AB$ results in a scalar which can be multiplied by $C$", but technically this is not true. $AB$ results in a $1 \times 1$ matrix, which cannot be multiplied by $C$ in your situation.

Comment: Hey can you look at my comment for user 247608..the gradient of the cost function for linear regression resulted in such a form

Comment: @SridharThiagarajan See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment, not a direct answer to your question:

You should understand three key facts (which maybe you do already, I can't tell):

1. Composing functions is associative.
2. Matrices correspond to linear functions between vector spaces.
3. Composing linear functions corresponds to multiplying matrices.

It will follow from these facts that matrix multiplication is "obviously" associative.

You may like to try to prove that above facts. For facts 2 and 3, the key concept is that linear maps are determined by the behavior on a basis, and this behavior is then encoded into a matrix (the columns of the matrix are the coordinates of the image of basis vectors). You can work out the algebra describing this.

For fact one, you have to think about what a function does to elements of a set.